# How to diagnose RAID drive showing incorrect size

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid

I have a software RAID1 array on Ubuntu 14.04. Each drive has 1TB, for a logical size of 500GB. Suddenly, one drive started reporting it only had 4.1GB and I can no longer run any SMART self tests on it. Doing so returns the error:

```
sk_disk_check_sleep_mode: Input/output error (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Is it safe to say that drive is dead, or is there possibly some misconfiguration? Oddly, Ubuntu's disk utility reports the "disk is OK, one bad sector".

Comment: Did you do anything with the [host protected area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area)?

Comment: @Hennes, I have no idea.

Comment: Try running `hdparm -N /dev/sda`. its output should look something like this: `/dev/sda: max sectors = 3906250000/3907029168, HPA is enabled`.

If it reads HPA is disabled then it is something else.

Comment: @Hennes, It reports the drive has no HPA.